# Making dice "prediction" thingy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

so i just make the mark rober experiment thingy
and when i plotted this thing and i get this error

```py
  File "C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (50,)
```

But when i add the numpy.random it worked, I don't know why.
And Here is my code.

```py
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9UAz2JekiI
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
import numpy as np
import random as r

times = 50
dices = 100
avg = ((6+1)/2)*dices
t = np.arange(0, 100)
rolls = []

for x in range(times):
    total = 0
    for i in range(dices):
        total += r.randint(1, 6)

    rolls.append(total)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t,np.array(rolls))

print()

ax.set(xlabel='Roll number', ylabel='Total',
       title='Dice normal distribution')
plt.ylim(100, 600)

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Answers will be appreciated

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It says the plot arguments need to be the same size. Notice that ```t``` is ```t = np.arange(0, 100)```, while ```rolls``` was created in a loop with ```range(times)```. But times is only 50, just like the error message is stating.

Comment: `t = np.arange(0, times)` instead of `t = np.arange(0, 100)`. Note that the variables `dices` and `avg` aren't used in the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you, That solve my problem